# RTOS connects via TCP to Local Server, but not to Remote Server

Tags: tcp, remote-server

I'm using an RTOS device and when trying to connect over TCP to a server I am running into some unusual results.

When connecting to a server on my local network, the connection is fine and I can see the packets flowing on Wire shark.

However, when attempting to connect to a remote server, one outside of my domain, the connection fails with an error code of:

TCP_ERR_NOSUCH_SOCKET (-4) --- Indicates that you have attempted to allocate a socket that 
does not exist.

This occurs during connect() function:

```
bool CTCP::Connect( const char * ipaddr, unsigned short port ) {
    IPADDR ip = AsciiToIp( ipaddr ) ;
    this->m_fdnet = connect( ip, INADDR_ANY, port, TICKS_PER_SECOND * 3);
    if( this->m_fdnet < 0 ) {
        CLogging::Debuglogf("[TCP] Error: Connection failed, error=[%d]", getsocketerror( this->m_fdnet ) );
        return false;
    }
    return true ;
```

I tried with two different remote servers, one with Google, and another one.

As a note:  I am able to ping both, and both of the ports are open.

I was wondering why this is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a colleage of @alexfontaine and we found that this problem is actually caused by the network setup of our office and has nothing to do with the connect code above.

See this question 
[DHCP IP address have access to the internet but static IP address don't behind a router](https://superuser.com/questions/353724/dhcp-ip-address-have-access-to-the-internet-but-static-ip-address-dont-behind-a)

Instead of deleting this question I am answering it with another question for the next person that might have this problem as well.